# Pandas groupby produce unexpected result for dataframe with Multiindex

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, group-by

I have a `pandas.DataFrame` with a Multiindex having 3 levels. I would like to groupby the first 2 levels and keep the largest value in the 3rd level. `pandas.groupby` produce an unexpected result. I'm wondering what's the cause. And is there any parameters I should add here?

```
idxslc = pd.IndexSlice

def keep_latest_info(df):
    print('Before:')
    print(df)
    if len(df) == 1:
       return df

    max_dt = df.index.get_level_values(-1).max()
    df = df.loc[idxslc[:, :, max_dt]]
    print('After:' )
    print(df)
    return df 

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(((1, 2, 2), (4, 9, 9), (5, 6, 7), (3, 9, 1)))).T.set_index([0, 1, 2])
df.index = df.index.rename('a-b-c'.split('-'))
df.groupby(level=[0, 1], group_keys=True, as_index=True).apply(keep_latest_info)
```

The results are as follows. As can be seen, the output of 2nd group (2nd & 3rd row) no longer has the level 3 index. Why is this?

```
Before:
       3
a b c   
1 4 5  3
Before:
       3
a b c   
2 9 6  9
    7  1
After:
     3
a b   
2 9  1


AssertionError: Cannot concat indices that do not have the same number of levels
```

Edit:
The result is caused by `IndexSlice`. If using `df = df.loc[idxslc[:, :, [max_dt]]]`  (with square bracket) in the function instead, everything works fine. Why does `IndexSlice` behave this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to how the slicing is being performed within the **keep_latest_info** function. When you slice the DataFrame using `df.loc[idxslc[:, :, max_dt]]`, it modifies the index levels, dropping the third level in this case.

To resolve this issue, you need to maintain the MultiIndex structure throughout the function. You can achieve this by modifying the keep_latest_info function as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

idxslc = pd.IndexSlice

def keep_latest_info(df):
    print('Before:')
    print(df)
    
    if len(df) == 1:
       return df

    max_dt = df.index.get_level_values(-1).max()
    df = df.loc[idxslc[:,:,max_dt], :]
    print('After:')
    print(df)
    return df 

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(((1, 2, 2), (4, 9, 9), (5, 6, 7), (3, 9, 1)))).T.set_index([0, 1, 2])
df.index = df.index.rename('a-b-c'.split('-'))

result = df.groupby(level=[0, 1], group_keys=True, as_index=False).apply(keep_latest_info)
```

Changes made:

1. Added `[:, :]` after `idxslc[:,:,max_dt]` to maintain all levels of the MultiIndex.
2. Changed `as_index=True` to `as_index=False` in the groupby function call to keep the index as columns in the resulting DataFrame.
   With these changes, the function will retain the MultiIndex structure throughout the operation, and you should get the expected output without any errors.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it possible to elaborate more on the cause of the different behavior using [idxslc] vs [idxslc, :] for dataframe.? My actual data is a  pd.Series. Please see my edit-part, if possible, what is the cause of the different behavior of the with/without square bracket?